# Проблема с функцией, а точнее с аргументами

Tags: функции, lua, аргументы, анонимная-функция

```lua
-- Анонимная функция
local add = function(a, b)
    return a + b
end

-- Передача функции в качестве аргумента
local function apply(func, x)
    return func(x)
end

print(apply(add, 3))
```

Можете помочь исправить?

```
lua: main.lua:3: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (local 'b')
stack traceback:
        main.lua:3: in function <main.lua:2>
        (...tail calls...)
        main.lua:11: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Comment: Если непонятен текст ошибки, то хотя бы посмотри, что делает функция add, и сравни с тем, как ты её хочешь использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `add (a, b)` требует двух аргументов. Внутри функции `apply (func, x)` передаётся только один.

Не вполне ясно, чего именно Вы хотели достичь. Вот два работающих варианта. В первом используется [вариативная функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F):

```lua
-- Передача функции в качестве аргумента
local function apply (func, ...) -- вариативная функция.
    return func (...) -- передача всех аргументов далее.
end

print (apply (function (a, b) -- это действительно анонимная функция.
    return a + b
end, 3, 4 --[[а это два требуемых ею аргумента]] ))
```

Во втором примере используется [замыкание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)):

```lua
local function add_this_much (add_this)
    return function (add_to) -- замыкание, получающее один аргумент.
        return add_to + add_this
    end
end

local add_three = add_this_much (3) -- получается функция, получающая один аргумент.

print (add_three (4))
```